# Get FLTK working on MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, fltk

I installed FLTK via the msys commandline for MinGW. It all seemed to work fine but when I try to run a simple program it reports this error:

```
    undefined reference to 'FL_Window::FL_Window(int, int, char const*)
```

I would have expected that to be defined already as it's the first code example from the manual I'm trying to get working here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was to compile from within the WinGW command line interface, not the regular windows command line.